# How to clear cache bins via the admin interface

Tags: 6, caching

Drush will allow you to selectively clear caches. CSS/JS or views for example.

Is there a way to do this via the admin interface, or a contrib module to do it? I don't have access to drush on a server and the cache rebuild is not reliable so it would be nice to just clear the cache bin that I need to.

Answer (score 3):

In D6 install the admin menu. By clicking on the favicon on the left hand side of the menu you can clear all/seleted caches.

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten about that. I'll keep open as I may not be able to use admin menu.

Comment: how about in D7? I'm not sure, but isn't this also built into the "admin menu" provided in core?

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 there is a new shortcut menu; simply add a shortcut to the performance page.

Comment: If you are using 6 you can also set up some actions to clear the cache bins with rules. So if a user creates content and you cache is not cleared for another hour as part of the final step in the Rules you can clear your cache.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just add a item somewhere in the admin menu, and create my own callback that does [cache_clear_all](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/6) on the table I want.  Normally I do this when I have my own cache table in a custom module, so this gets lumped with all the other admin menu entries for the module.